# CFG example: can double variable be replaced with 2 different assignments?

Tags: context-free-grammar

Say I have a context free grammar such as: S-> SaS | b | Λ... can S be "replaced" by 2 different S's at the same time...IE I understand "bab" and "bababab" are strings in this language...is "ba" an acceptable string in this language (SaS -> baΛ ->ba)?

Comment: This might be a better fit for cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: remember `^` is epsilon (null symbol) So, `S --> SaS ---> baΛ --->ba` is correct in last step we replace `S ---> ^` null means no symbol. It use conceptually but its not language symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Each variable in a context-free grammar is independent of all the others (that's the "context-free" part), so they may be expanded out to different strings.  In your case, it is true that `ba` is in the language of the grammar for precisely the reason you've specified.

Hope this helps!